# Swift repeated local notification set up

Tags: swift, xcode, uidatepicker, timepicker, localnotification

I am trying to set up daily repeated notifications with swift.

I am able to set up the notification by using

```swift
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.hour = 17
dateComponents.minute = 00
```

But I want the user to be able to change that, I set up a date picker and changed it to time only

In the date picker I was able to get it to save by doing the following

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    loadDate(animation: true)
}

func saveDate() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(TimePicker.date, forKey:dateKey)
}

func loadDate(animation: Bool) {
    guard let loadedDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: dateKey) as? NSDate else { return }

    TimePicker.setDate(loadedDate as Date, animated: animation)
}
```

How can I pass what was selected from hour and minute to the notification time? Also how would I be able to convert the time to 24 hours that way if they select 5 pm it goes to the date component as 17?

Thanks for any help

This is how I have the view controller. inside viewdidload. and then the timepicker is inside another viewcontroller

```swift
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound ]){(grandted,error)in }


let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Title"
content.body = "Body"

var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.hour = 17
dateComponents.minute = 18

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)


let uuidstring = UUID().uuidString

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidstring, content: content, trigger: trigger)

center.add(request) {(error) in}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you dong time selection on another view controller (second), you need to notify first (main) view controller that date have been changed.

Here many different ways to do it.   [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)
Choose any you like, for this example I will use notifications:

```swift
extension Notification.Name {
    /// Notification used to pass user selected date
    static let dateChanged = Notification.Name(rawValue: "DateChanged")
}
```

In second controller update save function:

```swift
func saveDate() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(TimePicker.date, forKey:dateKey)
    /// Send notification with new time
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .dateChanged, object: TimePicker.date)
}
```

In same time in main controller you need to subscribe to notifications:

```swift
deinit {
    /// We need to unsubscribe from notifications, otherwise app can crash
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    /// Subscribe to notifications 
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(dateChanged(_:)),
        name: .dateChanged,
        object: nil
    )
}

/// This method will be called when controller receive notification
/// It need to be annotated with @objc
@objc func dateChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
    let date = notification.object as! Date
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
    setNotification(with: components)
}

/// By always using same ID for local notifications 
/// You can easily remove them when time changes
private static let notificationID = "MyAppNotificationID"

func setNotification(with components: DateComponents) {
    /// Remove previously planned notification
    center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [MainVC.notificationID])

    /// Create new notificaion
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Title"
    content.body = "Body"
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: MainVC.notificationID, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    /// Add to center
    center.add(request) {(error) in}
}
```

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work anymore like that, for the trigger I still have it as dateComponents how would i replace it to user timepicker? Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @YT32Z please show how you create notification request

Comment: @ManWinBear. I edited the post and showed how the notification was set up. I have it inside the main view controller and then I have the date picker insider another view controller. I can put them in the same one if needed, but if I can call the function from another view it might be better. I am really new to swift so I am not sure on how to go about doing this. Also would this keep a deafult time? Thanks again

Comment: @ManWinBear Thank you so much for the help I really appreciate it that worked perfectly! You are the man